# Idiomatic Expression "at a loss"

Tags: expressions, idioms

Im trying to understand the idiomatic expression "at a loss." According to this source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/at+a+loss it can either mean "Below cost" or "Perplexed; puzzled." However, I'm wondering if it can also be used to mean the same as the definitions of the word "loss."

Can one say:

> "I'm at a loss of a pencil, can you help me find it?"

And would this have the same meaning as:

> "I lost a pencil, can you help me find it?"

Comment: Neither of the dictionary meanings is useful in the context and so will not be suitable. One **cannot** say *I'm at a loss of a pencil* as it would **not** have the same meaning as *I lost a pencil*. Just say *I lost a pencil*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two relevant expressions are:

> *I **am**/she **is**/they **are*** at loss

vs.

> **sold** at a loss

I will ignore the price *at a loss* expression here.

---

The meaning of *I am at a loss as to where my pencil is* is not the same as *I lost my pencil*. The former means I cannot reason my way as to where I have placed my pencil, emphasizing the thought process involved and the inability to draw a conclusion. The latter merely states a fact.

Thus, I can say

> I lost my pencil on the train when I gave it to James.

In that case, I cannot claim to be "at a loss", because I am fully aware of how I lost it.

Comment: Quite correct. The difference is between the predicate phrase _(be) at a loss (about `X`)_, which means '(be) confused (about `X`), (be) unable to explain `X`', and the phrase _at a loss_, which refers not to perception, but to the [Commercial Transaction Frame](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The expression "at a loss" is used to describe the noun's status that it follows. The car was sold at a loss means the sold price of the CAR is cheaper. And this phrase doesn't contain the meaning of being losing something.

so you can't say you are at a loss of a pencil

Comment: *is cheaper* requires something to compare it to...

Comment: Apparently, it compares with the price the owner bought his car

Comment: my comment is that your sentence is not correct English.

Comment: "being losing something" is not correct English